# How to insert a variable into another variable with bash

Tags: bash

I have a problem with a bash script.

I would like to insert a variable into another variable in a bash script, but the risult is not what I should expect.

Here the code

```
input1="inputnumber1"
input2="inputnumber2"
input3="inputnumber3"
dummy="input"
for i in $(seq 1 3)
do
    toprint=$dummy$i
    echo "$toprint"
done
```

I would expect this code print the content of the variable $input1, $input2 and $input3, but it just print input1, input2 and input3.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use ``{1..3}`` instead of seq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an indirect variable reference:

```
varname="$dummy$i"
toprint="${!varname}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Say:

```
echo "${!toprint}";
```

Also read [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006).  You can also read about indirect expansion in the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Answer (score 1):

Try the `eval` command:

```
eval toprint='$'$dummy$i
echo $toprint
```

[More on eval](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23111/what-is-the-eval-command-in-bash) on unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: That's  a nice one too!